# Using nginx modules with chef nginx cookbook

Tags: nginx, centos, chef-infra

I'm trying to use chef to provision a centos webserver with nginx. I want to use the http_auth_request_module and the headers_more_module. My role looks like this:

```
{
    "name" : "cms-aws",
    "description" : "a role to deploy cms to aws",
    "default_attributes" : {
        "nginx" : {
            "source" : {
                "modules" : ["nginx::http_auth_request_module","nginx::headers_more_module"]
            }
        }
    },
    "run_list" : [
        "runit",
        "python",
        "build-essential",
        "gunicorn",
        "nginx::source",
        "openssl",
        "yum",
        "git",
        "yum-epel",
        "my-custom-cookbook",
        "supervisor"
    ]
}
```

However, when I run nginx -V on the server, those modules aren't listed, and nginx complains when I use the auth_request directive in my conf file.

I've also tried with the following attributes, but chef couldn't find those cookbooks when I ran it:

```
"default_attributes" : {
    "nginx" : {
        "source" : {
            "modules" : ["http_auth_request_module","headers_more_module"]
        }
    }
},
```

Edit:
So I've determined that the AMI I was running this on already had nginx installed. So when systemctl starts nginx it's hitting the preexisting one, and not the one chef installs. I tried modifying my attributes as such:

```
"default_attributes" : {
    "nginx" : {
        "source" : {
            "modules" : ["nginx::http_auth_request_module","nginx::headers_more_module"]
        },
        "binary" : "/usr/sbin/nginx"
    }
},
```

but chef still installs nginx at `/opt/nginx-1.6.2/sbin/nginx`, any idea how to correct this?

Edit edit: Turns out nginx is not installed out of the box on this AMI, so the cookbook installs it at `/usr/sbin/nginx`, yet when I run `nginx -V` the desired modules aren't listed. When I run `/opt/nginx-1.6.2/sbin/nginx -V` it lists the requested modules.

Comment: On that box, what do you get when you run `which -a nginx` ? Basically, how many places in nginx installed/linked/found?

Answer (score 2):

Even if nginx was installed from a package, the nginx cookbook will create an runit service starting nginx from `/opt/nginx-1.6.2/sbin/`. You can manage it with the runit's [sv command](http://smarden.org/runit/sv.8.html)

```
sudo sv status nginx
sudo sv up nginx
```

When compiling nginx from source in chef, it makes sense to forcefully remove any existing packages in the same recipe:

```
package("nginx") { action :remove }
```

Since your nginx appears to be compiled correctly (`/opt/nginx-1.6.2/sbin/nginx -V` produces the correct result), the above should be enough to fix the issue.